# unset row from multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:
array one is named as $input that output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [reference_no] => 306334510
        [archive_no] => 20140102900152506
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [reference_no] => 22936619
        [archive_no] => 20140104900153643
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [reference_no] => 30211132
        [archive_no] => 20140109001536461
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [reference_no] => 3890623027301
        [archive_no] => 201401029001949791
    )

)
```

and second array named as $active that will output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [archive_no] => 20140102900152506
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [archive_no] => 20140104900153643
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [archive_no] => 2014010900133107
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [archive_no] => 2014010900152506
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [archive_no] => 2014010900153643
    )

)
```

So first I need to check for duplicated rows and I check it by 'archive_no'.
So far this works fine, but now I need to remove those duplicated rows from $input array.
My unset does not seem to work.

code so far:

```
public function RemoveDublicatedRows($input, $active){
    $output = array();
 foreach ($input as $inp) {
  foreach ($active as $act) {
   if ($act['archive_no'] == $inp['archive_no']) {
    $output[] = $act;
     foreach ($output as $out){
      if($inp['archive_no'] == $out['archive_no']){
    $inp = array($inp);
       unset($input[$inp]);
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
    return $output;
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an index instead of an array ($inp) here:

```
unset($input[$inp]);
```

Should be:

```
if($inp['archive_no'] == $out['archive_no'])
{
   $index = array_search($inp, $input);
   unset($input[$index]);
}
```

EDIT: some parts are useless in your code, here is a cleaned code:

```
public function RemoveDublicatedRows($input, $active)
{
   $output = array();
   foreach ($input as $inp) 
   {
      foreach ($active as $act) 
      {
         if ($inp['archive_no'] == $act['archive_no']) 
         {
            $output[] = $act; 
            // maybe you should consider storing $act['archive_no'] instead ? 
            // It's up to you, depends on what you need...

            $index = array_search($inp, $input);
            unset($input[$index]);
         }
      }
   }

   return $output;
}
```